# react native MainApplication.java method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

hi today i have installed react-native-maps in my project and i have configured it but when i run `react-native run-android` it show me an error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/valentino/Scrivania/test/android/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainApplication.java:38: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
1 error
```

[this is the link of the guide I followed on github to configure react-native-maps.](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

In the MainApplication.java I added `import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage`

and

```
@Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                  new MainReactPackage(),
                  new MapsPackage()
          );
      }
```

in the `public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {`.

do you know how I can overcome this problem?

**UPDATING**

after TheWanderer has solved the previous problem, the terminal shows me the following error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/valentino/Scrivania/test/android/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainApplication.java:38: error: method getPackages() is already defined in class <anonymous com.test.MainApplication$1>
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                                 ^
1 error
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [sample](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/example/ExampleApplication.java).

That method is part of the ReactNativeHost. You can see how it's all implemented there.

Comment: excuse in reality already is public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication { , I was wrong when I wrote the question. @TheWanderer

Comment: thanks for the help I have updated my question for a new bug in the same file you know how to fix it. @TheWanderer

Comment: That error means you have that method defined twice. Remove one of them.